# Who of the Rishonim had the title Rav, who had the title Rebbi and who had the title Rabbeinu?

Tags: rishonim

How do I know which title (Rav, Rebbi or Rabbeinu) did each of the Rishonim have? I see different books with different titles for the same person.

Comment: None of these titles are official. There is no "correct" one.

Comment: I heard it was actually incorrect to say "Rabbi Hillel" or "Rabbi Shammai".  Is this not so?